# Symfony2 - Image uploaded only displays when being called in the Twig file

Tags: image, symfony, file-upload, twig

I have an problem with displaying my uploaded image to web/images when using the following line below while inside of the blog text or using a data fixture.

I've tested it by manually calling in the code to display the image inside of the Twig file but I want to use this in a fixture/entering it in the blog text to customize the size/alignment of the images for each post.

Can someone show me what's preventing the image from displaying?

Cheers!

**This refuses to display image while in a fixture or inside blog text:** (shows an outline of the proper sizing and alignment of image inside the blog text but not the image itself)

```
<img class="alignleft" src="{{ asset(['images/', news.image]|join) }}" alt="" width="290" height="275" />
```

**Using a web link for an image works fine when in a fixture or when entering a blog text:**

```
<img class="alignleft" src="http://www.example.com/example.jpg" alt="" width="290" height="275" />
```

**Using autoescape false to display the blog text:**

```
{% autoescape false %}
   <p>{{ news.blog }}</p>
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: What about `{{ asset('images/yourimage.jpg') }}`, without the variable and join? (Btw, if you want only 1 variable not escaped/encoded, you can use `|raw` on it. No need for an `autoescape` block.)

Comment: No, that didn't work same result shows the alignment of where the pic is going and proper sizing but no image. Am using autoescape for displaying the other html code thats in the blog aside from the image.

Comment: You just fixed the code in the question. Was the missing closing `}}` just a copy/paste typo?

Comment: Soz, that was a typo on my end it has the }} and I tried what you just suggested and it doesn't work. As I said it's odd that it works if I just put this line into the Twig file itself but not from a fixture or entered text. I'm thinking Twig is blocking this somehow?

Comment: What is the rendered output inside the `src=".."` attribute?

Comment: I get the link as posted: `src="{{ asset(['/images/', news.image]|join) }}" />` when I click on it I get a `No route found for "GET /%7B%7B%20asset(['/images/',%20news.image]%7Cjoin)%20%7D%7D" (from "http://news.local/app_dev.php/")`

Comment: please see my answer. Guess that's what you're looking for, right?

Comment: FYI, instead of `['images/', news.image]|join`, you can concatenate using `~` operator: `'images/' ~ news.image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to render a string(variable) as a (sub-)template.

That's why twig isn't processing the `{{ asset() }}` function.

Auto-escaping is not what you're looking for as it doesn't enable processing of twig functions inside strings.

**solution:** 
*the template_from_string function*

1.) Enable the `Twig_Extension_StringLoader` extension that comes bundled with twig in your `config.yml`

```
services:
    # ...
    twig.extension.stringloader:
        class: Twig_Extension_StringLoader
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Now clear your cache using `app/console cache:clear`.

2.) If you have your template stored in a variable named `news.blog` you can now use the function as follows:

```
{{ include(template_from_string(news.blog)) }}
```

more information in the documentation: **[template_from_string](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html)**

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot, can you explain template stored in a variable?

Comment: You said the question's code is inside a blog (entry) text that's loaded by a fixture. So I guess the text/code itself is stored in a variable that you pass to twig from your controller ? Ah i see it's `news.blog` in your case. Updated the answer.

Comment: Is it working now? btw you can just use simple string concatenation instead of the join: `asset( 'images/' ~ news.image )`

Comment: Trying to figure how to set this up per the page. `$twig = new Twig_Environment(...); <-- what goes here?
$twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());`

Comment: I've updated the answer to include instructions how to enable the extension in `config.yml`. Be careful that you don't end up with multiple `services:` keys in a single config-file, as they will overwrite each other.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you nifr for showing me the steps to setup and your more than thorough answer. Genius sir! Learned something new today. Much obliged.